# Changes need to run mongoose on server instead of localhost?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What are the changes I need to run my app on server instead of localhost

[image]

Comment: `mongoose.connect` means to connect mongodb which running on `localhost`, not related to your app...

Comment: so what are the changes I need to run my this localhost mongo to run on heroku server ?????

Answer (score 0):

mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongoServerIP/dbName)

Since you are running your mongo in your local, you are using localhost. I am not familiar with heroku server, but in general case, you first need to make sure mongo db is running on your heroku server and than you need to put that IP instead of localhost in the above command.

Please refer http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html in case you need login credentials to access the server or any other reference.